# Multiple counters (Listview) android

Tags: java, android, listview, timer

I want to make a list of independent accountants. The code below adds the counter in the last list item.

```
 if (timeWaitBus != null) {
            Bus bus = eItem.getBus();
            nCounter = bus.getTimeWaitBus(bus.getId(), eItem.getIdStopBus());
            doTimerTask();
 }--


public void doTimerTask() {
    mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            if (nCounter == 0) {
                mTimerTask.cancel();
            }

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    timeWaitBus.setText(String.format("Tempo de chegada estimado em %s min", nCounter));// update TextView
                    nCounter--;
                }
            });
        }
    };
    // public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
    t.schedule(mTimerTask, 500, 3000);  //
}
```

Comment: Awesome! And your question is?

Comment: How work with N counters?

Comment: Your specific question is still very unclear.